# How to find MLE of p^2q^3 when X~B(n,p)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

How to find MLE of $$p^2q^3 $$when $$X_1,X_2,...,X_m $$ are iid random variable from B(n,p)

Comment: Is $q = 1 - p$ here?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming $q=1-p$ as usual, by the [invariance property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#/Functional_invariance), the MLE of $g(p)=p^2(1-p)^3$ is $$\widehat{g(p)}_{ML}=g(\hat{p}_{ML})$$
So, you'll find the ML estimate for $\hat{p}$ and apply the function $g(.)$.